# How to insert method in object in JavaScript and call it?

Tags: javascript, function, methods, javascript-objects

I've been looking for how to properly format a method in an object in javascript and how to execute it I keep getting errors and don't know how to call a method. console keeps giving me errors so I just wanted to ask if anyone knows how to properly place a method in an object and how to call it.

Comment: Please, add what you have tried so far...

Comment: What have you tried till now?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please do research before posting a question - and after research if you still can't figure it out ( which is fine ) please show what code you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var a = {
    m : "23",
    f : function(test) { return something; }
        }
```

Call the function-

```
a.f(parameter);
```

Comment: If you find this answer helpful mark it as correct so that it can help others too.

Answer (score 0):

its is very simple

```
const user = {
    firstName:"john",
    lastName:"doe"
}
user.fullName = function(){
    return user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName
}
console.log(user.fullName());
```

you can delete particular method or property by using delete

Answer (score 0):

On the new `ES6` there is actually a shorthand you can use, check next example:

```js
let myObj = {
    prop: "I'm a property",
    method(x) {return "Method called with argument " + x;}
}

console.log(myObj.prop);
console.log(myObj.method(5));
```

More info: [Method Definitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/Method_definitions)